# How to colour text based on IRC colours node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am using this code to show chat messages:

```
  socket.on('message', function(from,to,message){
    $('#messages').append('<li>' + from + ': ' + message + '</li>');
  });
```

However the messages contain IRC colour codes so appear as:

```
NIKKI: 13Hello Carolyn:)
```

http://node-irc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API.html#colors shows functions to wrap text in colour codes but it does not show any functions on how to convert incoming text in to their CSS equivalent colour. Is there some way to do it?